# Building python app for creating Spotify playlists

Tags: python, spotify

I am trying to build a Python program that creates Spotify playlists based on an input string.
I am using the pyspotify wrapper, and the Spotify API (libspotify, including license key). To install the pyspotify wrapper including the libspotify link I cloned the git repository (do not even now the meaning of this but I think that's what I did) and then ran installed Xcode4, and loaded command line tools. Then ran: sudo python setup.py install to install as instructed at http://pyspotify.mopidy.com/en/latest/introduction/.

However, I get the error msg:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-fused-madd'
src/module.c:3:10: fatal error: 'libspotify/api.h' file not found
#include "libspotify/api.h"
     ^
1 error generated.
error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
```

The `api.h` file is in the `pyspotify` folder, together with the `libspotify` folder and the application key. What do I need to do to make pyspotify install?

Thank you for your help!

/Erik

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by `setup.py` not finding your `libspotify` installation.

Before installing pyspotify you need to install libspotify. You can either:

1. download the tarball from Spotify's web site, unpack it, change into the dir you unpacked it to, and then run:

   ```
   ./configure && make && sudo make install
   ```
2. or install it using Homebrew by running:

   ```
   brew install libspotify
   ```

When libspotify is installed, you can install pyspotify from PyPI simply by running:

```
pip install pyspotify
```

There's no need for checking out the git repo and installing manually from it unless you're planning on coding on pyspotify itself. If you really want to have the very latest development version (there's currently very little difference between v1.11 and the git version), you can install it using:

```
pip install pyspotify==dev
```